# How to download chart package from Helm ChartMuseum?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I feel I have overseen something but I'm unable to find the appropriate section on https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum

How can I download helm chart package (.tgz) from Helm ChartMuseum (using curl, wget or any other cli)?

Helm must use that API to download requirements, but somehow I can't find the information in the ChartMuseum readme...

Answer (score 22):

Using **`helm v3`**:

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
helm repo update
helm pull stable/chartmuseum --untar # optionally untar
```

Comment: Note that there is a typo in the name of the chart

Comment: How to pull a particular version?

Answer (score 3):

Get it with curl:

```
curl https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/chartmuseum-2.5.0.tgz --output chartmuseum-2.5.0.tgz
```

All the packages from stable repo are here:

https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/

The latest version of chartmuseum to date is here:

https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/chartmuseum-2.5.0.tgz

The helm chart of chart museum on GitHub:

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/chartmuseum

Comment: Believe this answer is now non-functional, getting access denied and I think the site has changed.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy by using HELM cli tool you can used below steps to download charts locally

First add HELM repo

```
helm pull <REPO_NAME>/<PATH_TO_CHART> --version <CHART_VERSION>
```

Second download locally HELM charts

```
$ helm pull nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --version 0.10.5
```